# How to free memory from readahead()?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

Do I just use `free()` function to free the pointer, or some specific API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `readahead()` populates the page cache, memory is handled by the kernel. You don't do anything.

Comment: Thx, so when will kernel free the memory?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. This is like asking when the kernel will free its own memory following a `read()`.

Comment: If I close the file, will the memory be closed?

Comment: Again, you're asking the wrong question. It's kernel-level memory; the kernel will decide what to do with it. When you `close()` a regular file, the kernel can do whatever it wants with the buffer space that was set aside for cache. It is ludicrous for you to worry about that.

Comment: Thx for your kind explanation, I am actually solving a memory leakage problem. And increasing of the memory usage of the process is due to readahead call. So if the system memory is not enough, will kernel free some memory or just return "out of memory" error?

Comment: `readahead` has nothing to do with memory leaks or even memory usage in the ways that matter (commit charge, dirty pages, or virtual memory space). If you have a memory leak, look elsewhere for the cause.